# IIS 7 C# web service should log into intranet

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, iis-7

I try to run a web service which gets a list of pages and then should try to print this pages as pdf sites.
The problem is now, that the service has to authenticate. Because the HTTP server which hosts the pages is inside an intranet zone.

The service runs on an IIS7 and is written in C#.

Thanks for helping.

-lony

Comment: P.S.: I tried impersonating but it is not working, so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>Hopefully this should help;</strike>

[PRB: "Access Denied" Error Message When You Call a Web Service While Anonymous Authentication Is Turned Off](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/811318/en-us)

---

**Update:**

Sorry misunderstood your question, would you not use the HTTP Authorization header to do this? Something like;

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("url");
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "Password");
```

Comment: Thanks Lankymart for your response. It seams I my statement was not clear. I don't want to authenticate against my web service. The web service should authenticate against an Apache HTTP server which is inside an Intranet.
The flow is __User--[ListofSites]->WebService--[HTTP call]-->HTTP Server__